# What is the difference between 锋利， 尖利， 锐利， 锋锐，尖锐？

Tags: meaning, difference

All seem to mean sharp in both a literal and abstract way

Comment: web search using e.g. "翻译 sharp" will provide info about collocation: http://www.iciba.com/sharp  http://www.iciba.com/sharp  http://www.hujiang.com/ciku/sharp/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 锋= edge ; 利= sharp; **锋利**= **sharp (of edge)**
>
> Example:
>
> 刀锋**锋利** blade edge is **sharp**

~

> 尖= pointy; 利= sharp; **尖利**= **pointy and sharp**
>
> Examples:
>
> 冰錐是**尖利的** ice pick is **pointy and sharp**
>
> **尖利的**工具 (**pointy and sharp** tool)

~

> 锐 = piercing; 利= sharp; **锐利** = **piercingly sharp(of point)**
>
> Examples:
>
> 眼光**锐利** have (piercingly) **sharp** eyes
>
> **锐利**武器 **piercingly sharp** weapon

~

> 锋= edge; 锐 = piercing; **锋锐**= **piercingly sharp (of edge and point)**
>
> Example:
>
> **锋锐**武器 **piercingly sharp** weapons

~

> 尖= pointy; 锐 = piercing; **尖锐**= **piercingly pointy**
>
> Example:
>
> 說話**尖锐** speak in a (piercingly) **pointy** manner
>
> **尖锐的**工具 **piercingly pointy** tool

Answer (score 1):

锋利 and 锐利 are used for describing knives and swords, e.g.: a sharp knife. 尖锐 is now used for describing topics, viewpoints, or questions, e.g.: a sharp question. 尖利 and 锋锐 are rarely used, I hardly see these words. Theoretically you may create much more new words by these near synonym.

Answer (score 0):

锋利 describe a knife, something with a edge. 尖利 describe a needle, something with a point. 锋锐 is similar to 锋利, and 尖锐 is similar to 尖利. 锐利 probably would describe both, I am not sure.